# Camera works only first time in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UITabBarController and one of tabs is Camera Tab.

Camera Tab's controller is TakePhotoViewController. In TakePhotoViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    CameraViewController *controller = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:camController animated:YES];
}
```

When I close the camera, it does not works anymore. I want to open camera at any time, but It runs only first time when I touched Camera Tab. How can I solve it?

Thanks, Mert

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is only called, well, when the view first loads.  If you want to trigger an action every time the view appears, you'll have to do something else.

Comment: I feel so stupd. Thanks :)